# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'â€“' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, function

### this PROBLEM bug me out.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'â€“' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\*****\*****\functions.php on line 187
```

Line 187 across line 9 in the code box below. **At** `$zjd = (int)((1461...`

### What is this ?

This is function prints out Hijri Calender, Which it depends on the moon, it different from the Gregorian calendar which it depends on the sun. `Date();` function prints out Gregorian date,and there isn't any function for the Hijri date (Called also Islamic Calender). and there is difference between these two. for example years in Gregorian Calendar is 365.25 but in Hijri Calender is 354.367. and also in months... etc.

### What happened?

I made a function converts Gregorian to Hijri, but it wasn't that accurate so I searched the web for one.
I found a lot accurate ones, but written in JavaScript. and Just found this fine only piece written in PHP.

I tried to contact the writer about the problem but he didn't respond. posted this on 2011.

### Part of the function

```
function hijriCal(){
$theDate     = getdate();
$wday        = $theDate['wday'];
$hr          = $theDate['mday'];
$theMonth    = $theDate['mon'];
$theYear     = $theDate['year'];

if (($theYear > 1582) || (($theYear == 1582) && ($theMonth > 10)) || (($theYear == 1582) && ($theMonth == 10) && ($hr > 14))) {
$zjd = (int)((1461 * ($theYear + 4800 + (int)(($theMonth – 14) / 12))) / 4) + (int)((367 * ($theMonth – 2 – 12 * ((int)(($theMonth – 14) / 12)))) / 12) – (int)((3 * (int)((($theYear + 4900 + (int)(($theMonth – 14) / 12)) / 100))) / 4) + $hr – 32075;
} else {
$zjd = 367 * $theYear – (int)((7 * ($theYear + 5001 + (int)(($theMonth – 9) / 7))) / 4) + (int)((275 * $theMonth) / 9) + $hr + 1729777;
}
```

### Thanks in advance

Comment: `â€“` is the long hyphen. Don't copy & paste code from websites which prettify it.

Comment: ah thats what it is, was going to say copy and paste this into notepad or something else to remove any special chars.

Comment: @shapeshifter copied it to notepad and paste it and didn't work same problem.

Comment: Yeah its a valid character you will need to replace the long hyphens with "normal" hyphens.  Do a search and replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a wrong character on `–` (ascii: 161) rather than `-` (ascii: 45).

Here is the the replaced version.

```
function hijriCal(){
$theDate     = getdate();
$wday        = $theDate['wday'];
$hr          = $theDate['mday'];
$theMonth    = $theDate['mon'];
$theYear     = $theDate['year'];

if (($theYear > 1582) || (($theYear == 1582) && ($theMonth > 10)) || (($theYear == 1582) && ($theMonth == 10) && ($hr > 14))) {
$zjd = (int)((1461 * ($theYear + 4800 + (int)(($theMonth - 14) / 12))) / 4) + (int)((367 * ($theMonth - 2 - 12 * ((int)(($theMonth - 14) / 12)))) / 12) - (int)((3 * (int)((($theYear + 4900 + (int)(($theMonth - 14) / 12)) / 100))) / 4) + $hr - 32075;
} else {
$zjd = 367 * $theYear - (int)((7 * ($theYear + 5001 + (int)(($theMonth - 9) / 7))) / 4) + (int)((275 * $theMonth) / 9) + $hr + 1729777;
}
```